# Cannot load dll from another computer

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue with loading a dll from another computer. It loads pretty fine from my station but when I tried testing it from another system that hasn't got Visual Studio installed, I get the following exception:

> Date - 10 May 2012 12:01:48.0725000 - Exception has been thrown by the target of an      invocation.
>       Date - 10 May 2012 12:01:48.0881250 - System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load   file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>       File name: 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>       at ZENNLNGLIB.Process.ReadConfigFile() 
>       at ZENNLNGLIB.Process.ProcessFile(String fileName)
>
> Assembly manager loaded from:    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
>       Running under executable  C:\Documents and   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\NLNG.Encryption\NLNG.Encryption\bin\Debug\NLNG.Encryption.exe
>       --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>       LOG: User = WS001ITS106\Administrator
>       LOG: DisplayName = System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>       (Fully-specified)
>       LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/NLNG.Encryption/NLNG.Encryption/bin/Debug/
>       LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>       Calling assembly : ZENNLNGLIB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>       ===
>       LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
>       WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be     probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
>       LOG: No application configuration file found.
>       LOG: Using machine configuration file from  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>       LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and  Settings/Administrator/Desktop/NLNG.Encryption/NLNG.Encryption/bin/Debug/System.Xml.Linq.DL L.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and  Settings/Administrator/Desktop/NLNG.Encryption/NLNG.Encryption/bin/Debug/System.Xml.Linq/Sy stem.Xml.Linq.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/NLNG.Encryption/NLNG.Encryption/bin/Debug/System.Xml.Linq.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/NLNG.Encryption/NLNG.Encryption/bin/Debug/System.Xml.Linq/System.Xml.Linq.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/zennlnglib/System.Xml.Linq.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/zennlnglib/System.Xml.Linq/System.Xml.Linq.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/zennlnglib/System.Xml.Linq.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL  file:///C:/zennlnglib/System.Xml.Linq/System.Xml.Linq.EXE.

This is how I'm loading my dll:

```
Assembly u = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\test\test.dll");

    Type t = u.GetType("Test.Process");
    MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("ProcessFile");

    try
    {
        object[] myparam = new object[1];
        myparam[0] = @"C:\test\testFile.csv";

        result = (string)m.Invoke(null, myparam);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
```

Comment: are u sure you have this file in this path ? @"C:\test\testFile.csv

Comment: the exception is self-explained , look for the dll in c:\test\ folder.

Comment: Is the correct verion of .net installed on the other computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load   file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

pretty says what happens. Check if the right version (3.5) of the .NET Framework is installed on the other machine where the error occurs.

if you try to load it from the locations which are printed below, look for the System.Xml.Linq dll in

> C:/zennlnglib/System.Xml.Linq.DLL

I guess

> C:/Documents and  Settings/Administrator/Desktop/NLNG.Encryption/NLNG.Encryption/bin/Debug/

does not exist at the target machine.